# Swift - How to keep reference to old view controller when instantiating new view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to programmatically instantiate a new view controller of the same type as my original view controller using this code:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(StoryboardKeys.ViewIdentifier), animated: true)
```

I would like the user to be able to go back to my original view controller, so I was wondering if there is a way to keep the old view controller in memory? Also if I instantiate a view controller this way, do I get to prepareforsegue (in order to programmatically add a back button)? If not, how could I add a back button when pushing this view controller?

I suspect there is a better way to do this, so if there is, please let me know. Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UINavigationController maintain your view controllers as a stack automatically, so don't worry about your view controller's memory management.
Only if you want a custom back button, otherwise you don't have to add a back button by yourself, everything has been done.

Comment: but what if i want to push an instance of the exact same view controller to the top?

Comment: I can't see a reason why you would do that. But if you have to, you can init a new view controller. If you push your current view controller to stack, I think you would get a exception.

Comment: If you want to come back, you can use     self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` somewhere in your second view controller . Navigation controller contains a stack of views that you can retrieve by using `self.navigationController!.viewControllers`. You can modify this stack as you like.